# Symfony2 basic http auth, works with curl but not on Android

Tags: android, httpwebrequest, http-headers, symfony

I'm trying to authenticate a user on my symfony2 server.
The authentication works with curl in cli :

```
 curl "http://localhost:8080/app_dev.php/app/user/profile.json?id=4" -u foo:bar --basic
```

But with Android i always get a 401 error with this error:

```
 A Token was not found in the SecurityContext.
```

What can I do to fix it ?

Here is my security.yml:

```
security:
providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_manager
encoders:
    BumpMe\UserBundle\Entity\User: sha512

firewalls:
    app:
        pattern: ^/app/.*
        stateless: true
        security: true

        http_basic:
            realm: "API"
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true


access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/app/, role: ROLE_USER }

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
```

Also, how can i send the username and the password in base64 ? Because currently on Android it doesn't want the base64 and curl sent it on base64...

I don't understand this error...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry i find out...

It's just because Symfony wanted a base64 encoded.
The base64 encoding didn't work on Android because, the method add a new line after the encoded datas so, it's not the same...

With a simple trim it's fine :

```
"Basic "+Base64.encodeToString((login+":"+pass).getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT).trim();
```

I think it can be helpful.